# *.sty file not found

Tags: packages, miktex, texniccenter, elsarticle

This question is very similar to a previous post:
[Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files/20121#20121)

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXnicCenter to compose and execute my LaTeX file(s) on Windows 7. I am using a template from Elsevier to submit a journal article, but I am getting the LaTeX Error that File 'numcompress.sty' not found. This file is currently located in the same directory as the other `elsarticle` files: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex 2.9\tex\latex\elsarticle`. I have actually followed the directions posted to the above question exactly: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20121/ but still have had no change in outcome.

Comment: If numcompress.sty is in this directory, and you clicked refresh FNDB, it should works. Did you try to compile your file without TeXnic center?

Comment: Here's a walk through on downloading, compiling and installing your own custom latex packages: https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/systems/tex/new-packages.html

Answer (score 19):

Are you using MikTeX as User or as administrator? To be safe change to adminstrator, check wheather your file `numcompress.sty` is really in the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex 2.9\tex\latex\elsarticle`. Now start MiKTeX 2.9 over `Windows start` -> `all programms`.  Choose `Maintenance (Admin)`, then `Settings (admin)` (Admin is important!). Now choose `General` and click `Refresh FNDB`. Afterwards you can change to user again and run MiKTeX. `Refresh FNDB` means refresh your database for the used filenames.

Answer (score 7):

As others answer already said: You should update the FNDB in admin mode if you put files in the main miktex tree. But it is not recommended to use this tree for local additions. Your additions can get lost when miktex updates packages. Use either one of the other trees (UserConfig or CommonConfig) or (better) use a new local tree: Create (e.g.) `C:\mylocaltree\tex\latex\elsarticle`, copy your file in this folder and then add `C:\mylocaltree` as a new root in miktex settings.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The others are advising you to create big headaches for yourself in the future, or anyone else who needs to compile your source. If you add a local file to the distibution tree, it will get lost when you upgrade to a new version, and you will no longer be able to compile any document that uses it.

Answer (score 5):

First, launch the [Windows cmd line as administator](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/) and search for an `.sty` file that you know is present and works using the [findtexmf](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/findtexmf.html) utility, e.g.

```
findtexmf colortbl.sty
```

Ensure that your `.sty` file is in a similar location.

Now, update the filename database using the [initexmf](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/initexmf.html) utility:

```
initexmf --admin -u
initexmf --admin --dump
```

The first one refreshes the filename database and the second performs other updates. You may not need both but it won't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

With MikTeX installed you have access to Texworks at the All Programs/MikTeX/ menu.  Try loading and compiling from that IDE. If it will not compile from TeXworks then the *.sty has not been properly registered.

If this fails then use My Computer and actually verify that the files are exactly where you think they are.  (The Windows defaults for file saving can easily trip you up.)

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely **do not** add a local file to your MikTeX distribution folder.  You will create a big headache when you upgrade, it disappears, and you will no longer be able to compile your document.  The journal might not even still have the version you need available for download when you want to recompile it years later.

Ulrike Fischer’s answer is the only one so far that’s correct, but there are several good places to put the file:

- [Add a second root to MikTeX,](https://jekyll.math.byuh.edu/other/tips/miktexmacros.shtml) such as `C:\texmflocal\`.  Put it in an appropriate subdirectory, such as `C:\texmflocal\tex\latex\`.
- Create a local texmf root in your user directory and select it with the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable. This lets you have one that isn’t turned on for everyone all the time.
- Put the file in your project folder. Then, you can be sure it will be archived along with the source files that need it.  It’s a short text file and you have terabytes of disk space.

After you put a new file in a user directory, you must update the file names database under the MikTeX Tasks menu, or run `texhash`.

Comment: I have this very problem with a package (I think I have no choice, for this one I must install the .sty separately). I use TeXLive on Linux, when I put the .sty at its place, I must run `sudo mktexlsr` in order to have it available for compilation. `mktexlsr` (without `sudo`) does not show error messages, but just does nothing (it tells each step is skipped do not only read the final `Done.` message).

Comment: @zezollo With TeX Live on Linux, you can install to your TEXMFLOCAL directory. Type `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMGLOCAL` to find it. You can similarly find `TEXMFHOME` and install it there only for yourself. Re-run `texhash` when you’re done.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS system:

1. Open your terminal.
2. Find an `.sty` file that you know is present and works, for example `bm.sty`.
3. In your terminal put: `kpsewhich bm.sty`.

   It will show the path, for example:
   `/users/yourname/Library/TinyTex/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/bm.sty`.
4. Go to that folder (<kbd>Command + Shift + G</kbd>) on your desk. Put the path without `tools/bm.sty`.
5. Search and download the package that you don't have, then put it in that folder. Or you have own `.sty file`, just put it in that folder.
6. Go to terminal, put: `sudo teshash`.
7. The package will work.

Comment: Welcome! This is not good advice, I'm afraid. Local and custom files shouldn't be in `texmf-dist`. You should use, say, `TEXMFHOME`. On a Mac, this is usually in `/Users/<username>/Library/texmf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vector to add all the packages that you may need and then use the for loop to install all of them from the R terminal.

packs <- c("`setspace.sty'", "`float.sty'", "`amssymb.sty'", "`utf8.sty'", "`fancyhdr.sty'", "`tabularx.sty'", "`hyperref.sty'", "`etoolbox.sty'", "`lmodern.sty")

for (i in 1:length(packs)) {
tinytex::parse_install(text = paste('! LaTeX Error: File', packs[i],'not found.'))
}

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is what happened to OP, but it happened to me: a missing comma in my `usepackage` statement meant that instead of searching for both `relsize.sty` and `setspace.sty`, LaTeX tried searching for `relsizesetspace.sty`.