# How often do I have to synchronize MikTeX?

Tags: miktex, updating

This is a follow-up question of [media9.sty not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107526/media9-sty-not-found).

Basically, I had to synchronize MikTeX in order to get the package.

So, how often do I have to synchronize MikTeX in order for it not to miss any package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the activity of the package writing community. Whenever a new package arrives on CTAN (half a dozen per week, I guess) it takes a few days until they are available in MiKTeX. If you don't want to miss any of these, do one database and one package update per week. New packages are announced in the comp.text.tex newsgroup.

Comment: MikTeX has a strange feature to be inaccurate. Automatic updates fail when a package is removed as obsolete. There was  a recent story with amsmath, another with some binary (sorry, I forgot exact name). In such a case, I was forced to install missed packages manually. A practical rule is to make a local repository which is not synchronized with miktex servers and is somewhat obsolete.

Comment: A WWW alternative for CTAN announcements: http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/ (RSS feed available).

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov: There’s an error in your thinking: New packages are never installed automatically. But I agree, that it should be solved differently in cases like the recent amsmath issue.