# up-to-date TeX distribution

Tags: greek, distributions

In order to use the "LGRx package" I've been told in a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100690/how-can-we-write-in-greek-with-computer-modern-font?noredirect=1#comment235976_100690) that I've made, that I should have an up-to-date TeX distribution.

So, I wonder what is this and how can I install it to my PC?
Note that my OS is the windows 7.

Comment: Have you installed a recent version of either MikTeX or TeX Live? They are TeX distributions.

Comment: I have installed MikTeX 2.9 version.

Comment: Then you have the latest stable version of MikTeX. To make sure it's up to date, i.e. that you have the latest version of all packages, you have to run the update manager. See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/55473#55473) for details. Also, if you installed the Basic version of MikTeX then `lgrx` may not be installed, but you can install that package with MikTeX's Package Manager.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

As of today, MikTeX  version 2.9 is the latest stable distribution, so you should be fine for now.

However, for future refence (and based on Torbjorn), you should check:

[How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution#55473)

Also, I recommend you give a little read to this question, since you are also trying to use a package:

[How often do I have to synchronize MikTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107534/how-often-do-i-have-to-synchronize-miktex)