# Environment lstlisting undefined

Tags: listings, environments

Hi I have installed the listings package in order to display my code. I am running the following code within my document:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Hello World");
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

But that is giving me the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment lstlisting undefined.
```

I have mentioned `\usepackage{listings}` so I really dont know what the problem can be. Would anyone be kind enough to help or guide me the right way?

EDIT: Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{times,a4wide}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Hello World");
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you take a look at this question? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107534/how-often-do-i-have-to-synchronize-miktex

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @MarioS.E. Errrm why?

Comment: @Matt9Atkins because I had a problem like that once, and even though I was loading the package with `\usepackage` I had to synchronize MiKTeX

Comment: @Matt9Atkins Well, actually... are you using MikTeX?

Comment: @MarioS.E. Yes I am using MikTeX

Comment: @MarioS.E. How do I synchornise?

Comment: What I really wanted to point you too  was this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64133/sty-file-not-found

Comment: @egreg MWE is added. I tried the MWE in a separate document and it work, just doesnt seem to work in my current document

Comment: @Matt9Atkins then the package is installed... try running your present document with only the `listings` environment commented.  check for any other errors

Comment: @MarioS.E. I algo get this error: LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `listings', but the package provides `listing'.

Comment: @Matt9Atkins FYI: Your MWE works fine... TeX Live 2012, Mac OS

Comment: It works fine in a new doc by just not in my current doc, any reasons why?

Comment: Well, as an immediate workaround you could put your code inside a `verbatim` environment (\begin{verbatim} your code \end{verbatim}).  However, there must be a reason why you are having this problem

Comment: having the exact same problem, looks like an "illegal" character (obtained by a copy-paste action) is the cause of the error message. I can't say more ;-)

Comment: do `\usepackage{listings}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the information you have given us, and due to the fact that your MWE runs OK in several of our systems (and even yours when pasted into a new document) I humbly conclude that there must be a typo somewhere in your original document.

As an immediate workaround, you could use the `verbatim` environment:

```
\begin{verbatim}
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Hello World");
}
\end{verbatim}
```

But as mentioned before, this code runs perfectly on my system:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Hello World");
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ok so all you need is `\usepackage{listings}` - why not put that at the top of the answer?