# Updating MikTeX fails: "Windows API error 5: Acces denied."

Tags: errors, miktex, windows, updating

I've been using the "basic stuff" from LaTeX for slightly more than a year for university, but now I try to use a template from [LaTeX Templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/). When I try to compile the downloaded TeX file, I get a lot of (fatal) error messages because the packages which should be used can't be found, e.g.,

```
file 'lettrine.sty' not found
```

I use Texmaker and MiKTeX and found out I had to [update MiKTeX](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/updating.html), but when I want to update, I get an error message from the update wizard:

The operation could not be completed for the following reason: Windows API error 5: Acces denied. Details: C:
Can anyone help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) have you seen [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: I had this problem once and @sevenkul’s answer at [Windows API error 5: "Access is denied" when trying to compile TikZ picture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78674) fixed it for me. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you, it finally worked. Apparantly for some strange reason my program files not only contain a MiKTeX 2.9 folder but also a MiKTeX 2.9_2 and a MiKTeX 2.9_3 folder, and I also needed to change the security settings for the last two of them to make the update succeed.

Comment: @Wouter Glad it works; we’ll close this question as a duplicate then, just to keep things tidy. As for the multiple folders: That sounds like there are several (at least attempted) installations on your machine, could that be the case? You can check under control panel→programs. If this turns out to be the case and you’re comfortable with stuff like this, I’d recommend uninstalling all existing installations, thoroughly cleaning up with a tool like *CCleaner* or *Advanced SystemCare*, and then installing MiKTeX again. But most likely, things are gonna work the way they are now.

Answer (score 1):

As per question [*.sty file not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64133/sty-file-not-found), question [media9.sty not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107526/media9-sty-not-found) and [How often do I have to synchronize MikTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107534/how-often-do-i-have-to-synchronize-miktex), you should try these things:

1. Load the package manager as administrator and try to download the package
2. Refresh the FNBD
3. Synchronize MikTeX

Comment: When a package is freshly installed you do not have to “synchronize” again.