# File `subfigure.sty' not found

Tags: errors, packages

`File subfigure.sty not found.`

How can I fix this error? I compile my `.tex` file without any error with my laptop but I get this error when I compile with my office PC.

Comment: Seeing your comment at Heiko's answer, your problem seems to be a duplicate of [Windows API error 5: “Access is denied” when trying to compile TikZ picture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51799/27635) and not the one you've described in your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both TeX Live and MiKTeX provide both [`subfigure`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) and [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) as distribution packages. Both packages are written by the same author. The newer package `subfig` replaces the older package, but it is not fully backward compatible (see the package documentation).

Unless you have an ancient TeX distribution, you can install the missing package via the package manager of your TeX distribution. As `subfigure` is deprecated, you might consider using package `subfig` instead (the latter also requires package [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption)).

Comment: although i am the admin i can not install the missing package via the package manager since i m getting error 
`Windows API error 5: Access is denied`

Comment: Try reading this duplicate: [Updating MikTeX fails: “Windows API error 5: Acces denied.”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107586/27635) and the related question.

Answer (score 5):

If you have no rights to install packages on your office PC, simply put the file `subfigure.sty` (e.g. http://www.tug.org.in/tutorial/src/subfigure.sty) into your working directory.

Comment: subfigure is a basic package that should be included with any latex installation; having to put it in your working directory is likely not the right solution but is just masking the problem

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OSX (maybe even for other systems), there might be a conflict with different installed tex systems. In my case, a spurious Macports latex was in my path while I wanted MacTex. One test is

```
eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
```

Then run pdflatex. If it suddenly works, then its a PATH problem.