# How do I install mtpro2 on Windows?

Tags: packages, installing

I have been unsuccessful in getting the `mtpro2` package to work.

I am running WinEdt 7 and MiKTeX 2.9 in Windows 7.

I'm about to give up on it, but I really want the `\widehat` feature to produce really wide hats (as per [Really wide hat symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol))

Does anyone have a guide for dummies?  Perhaps a video on how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps these will help:

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64133/sty-file-not-found

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107526/media9-sty-not-found

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107534/how-often-do-i-have-to-synchronize-miktex

Comment: What about [this guide](http://www.pctex.com/kb/56.html)?

Comment: Well, let's start from the beginning.  Have you include the package by typing: `\usepackage{mtpro2}` at the preamble of your document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the MTpro2 Lite package (http://pctex.com/mtpro2.html#MTPro2_Lite). You will get a file `mtp2lite.zip.tpm`. Despite the ending you can unzip it to some folder e.g. with 7zip. You will get beside other a folder `texmf`. Open miktex settings and add this `texmf` folder as a new root. Then either add to your document `\pdfmapfile{=mtpro2.map}` or add the map permanantly to your system by following the description in the documentation of miktex http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/advanced.html#psfonts.

Use the package with the lite-option. E.g

```
 \usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
```

Comment: Thanks!   Everything is working now.  Your instructions were more clear than what they have on the site.  the problem was that instructed me to move the contents of textmf to a folder and point to that as root.  rather than point to textmf.

Comment: Also, I use notepad to add    

# MathTimePro II 
Map mtpro2.map
 
to the bottom of my updmap.cfg file located in C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config 

but that doesn't work.  adding \pdfmapfile{=mtpro2.map} directly to my .tex does, however, work perfectly.  Not sure why.

Comment: Don't change the main updmap.cfg. Follow the instruction in the miktex documentation in the link instead.

Comment: initexmf --edit-config-file updmap opened up a blank looking file for me... strange.  I just manually edited it and then ran initexmf --edit-config-file updmap and it worked. :)

Thank you!

Comment: Naturally it is blank the first time. The command opens your local configuration file.