# MiKTeX Options submenu is greyed out in WinEdt 6.0

Tags: miktex, include, winedt, mtpro

I have included the package `mtpro2` in my latex document using

`\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}`

as recommended [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110894/how-do-i-install-mtpro2). The main reason is that I need very wide tildes, if that matters.

I am using Winedt 6.0. When I try to follow the instructions at the link and add the `texmf` folder as a new root by going to

`tex -> miktex -> miktex options`

I find that all the submenus under the `miktex` submenu are greyed out (including update).

So firstly I wonder why this is occurring and how to fix it, and secondly if there is another approach I can take. Please keep in mind that I am very new to using this ide and have only used the GUI (so I don't know any command line shortcuts at this point).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hard to help, as WinEdt 6 is rather old. Can't you consider updating to WinEdt 8.2 (soon WinEdt 9!), that has many new functionalities and is now a unicode editor? Other way to go: launch MiKTeX Options from windows `Start Menu`.

Comment: I don't know about the Winedt menus, but there's no need to access MikTeX options through there; you can do it directly. Go to `Start -> All Programs -> MiKTeX 2.9 → Maintenance → Settings` to open the MikTeX options dialog. _Note:_ this will configure a personal tree accessible to your user account only. To configure a personal tree for more than one user, use the `(Admin)` variants from the MikTeX Start Menu entries instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) 

I can't get a more recent version of winedt because 6.0 is the license that my school has.

Answer (score 1):

WinEdt version 9 is the current one. Your should update.

I guess your problem is that you are not the administrator of the computers. So it could be that you are not allowed to change the computer for example with an update for MiKTeX.

Contact your local administrator and tell him which updates you need or ask him (he should knew the installation) how to do it.

Generally can you start MiKTeX updates by clicking on the windows start button, the choose "all Programs" and click on "MiKTeX 2.9". With clicking on "Maintanace" you can start updates and so on (if you are allowed to do it). I use only this way to update my system.

Comment: whoa version 9. I'm getting old.

Comment: Let me put it like this I've switched to WinEdt 5.4 and MiKTeX 2.4 after some time :)

Comment: Yes, I used it via MS-Dos for a very short amount of time but for the dating tool :P no unfortunately not.