# Alternatives to `mtpro2`?

Tags: newtxmath, times

I would like to typeset math in Times New Roman and have tried installing the `mtpro2` fonts, with no success. I would like to know if there is a package that offers an alternative in correcting the shortcomings of packages like `newtxmath`: I would especially like to change the way greek letters, sums and integrals look like – apart from other details.

Here's an example of what I get with `newtxmath` (`varvw` option selected):
[image]
Here's what the same formula looks like in a Springer textbook (which has the looks I'm aiming for):
[image]
Notice the completely different integral / sum signs, the different slant of the letter χ (the letters δ, ε, and λ, among others, have the same issue), and the way `newtxmath` "compresses" the letters in the limits of integration.

Comment: Why? There is the lite version of `mt2pro`: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite. You can use also `mathastext` package. Can you add your minimal example?

Comment: `mtp2lite` is not present in the MacTeX distribution; as I said, I've tried to download it but haven't managed to make it work so far.

Comment: installing mtpro2 lite is easy, download everything as zip from ctan, it will contain a texmf (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf) and then you can attach this as a new root, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110918/2388. But I would suggest to sent the newtxmath maintainer a mail and ask if he is willing to change the font or add new options.

Comment: I have done so, bearing in mind that my distribution is MacTeX. I put the zipped file in my local texlive directory and run the script at https://github.com/jamespfennell/mathtime-installer. The installation was not successful – I think because it couldn't find the .map file (even though it was downloaded from ctan like everything else). I have tried to follow the directions at PCTeX, but those didn't work either.

Comment: As to letter slant, the answer here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220, allows (in pdflatex) the letter slant of individual letters to be changed.

Comment: sorry I seem to have misread mactex to miktex, with mactex you can use `tlmgr conf auxtrees add path/to/the/texmf`  to attach the tree and then you will have to either add the map in the document with `\pdfmapfile` or use updmap-sys to activate it.

Comment: I have run the command line (with `sudo`) and re-run the installer script linked above. "There appears to have been an error in installation."

Comment: the mathtime fonts and packages haven't seen updates for many years, and the last time I looked the link at the pctex page was actually dead. I would never use some old installation script to install them without having checked very carefully if it still adapts to a current texlive on my OS.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hi, I add the last updated: © 2009. All Rights Reserved - Personal TeX, Inc. - Site last updated Thu, 07 Mar 2013 11:24:01 -0800.

Answer (score 3):

Here I put just a fragment of your image....using `mathastext`: it is not clearly `mt2pro` but it is similar..

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper, openright]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[italic,defaultmathsizes,symbolgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}\int^{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}_{0}{u^{2n-2}}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```