# I'm facing a problem with mtpro2

Tags: miktex, mtpro, newtx

[image]I appreciate efforts of those that aided me on my newtxtext, newtxmath problem. I have now updated my TeX distribution (MiKTeX) and now I was able to run the code as edited here which didn't initially run. Right now, I tried running a code with mtpro2 as follows and I got the error below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, openany, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{phfthm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{currency}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
 
\usepackage[urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=red]{hyperref}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

%%% theorems
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}

%%% commands
\newcommand{\lra}{\Longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\llra}{\Longleftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\call}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\inl}{\textup}
\newcommand{\sbs}{\subset}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother


%%% metadata
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
Body
\end{document}
```

From the logfile:

```
Couldn't open `mt2e.cfg' 
[…]
miktex-maketfm: major issue: User/administrator updates are out-of-sync.

! Font \MTEXA@=mt2exa at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \font 
l.130 \font
           \MTXL@=mt2xl at \the\dimen@
?
```

Comment: I edited your logfile down to the relevant parts. In general, try to keep your MWE short and relevant. That said, there seem to be multiple issues, one of them your MikTeX setup being out of sync. Please update MikTeX in both user User and Admin mode to solve that one.

Comment: Ok. I shall do that and get back to you

Comment: I already updated my packages yesterday and right now I checked for updates both in user and admin mode and there were no updates.

Comment: kindly check attached photo.

Comment: What would be the reason to load both `newtx` and `mtpro2`?

Comment: Can you help me edit the code so I use only mtpro2 then?

Comment: Running only mtpro2 still gives error.

Comment: I have now been able to use mtpro2 following instructions from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110894/how-do-i-install-mtpro2-on-windows