# LyX --- LaTeX error: File 'etex.sty' not found

Tags: lyx, viewers

I went to create a PDF of my work on LyX (by clicking the eyeballs on the top-left of the document), but it won't let me. [image]

What does this mean? How can I recover the document so that I can view the PDF? This work was done on a different laptop, so I saved the file to a flash drive and uploaded it to a different laptop before this error occurred.

Comment: Are you using MikTeX?

Comment: Well I was told to download MikTex before LyX, but that's about it. So not directly, but I'm sure LyX is.

Comment: You are running windows, right?

Comment: Yes. 8, but I've never had that problem before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, your problem is quite simple: you are not finding the package file [`etex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etex).

As it seems you are somewhat new to MikTeX, so I would recommend you go through this question as a starting point: [What is MikTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107599/what-is-miktex)

Later on, for maintenance purposes, you may want to check these questions:
[How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation) and [How often do I have to synchronize MikTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107534/how-often-do-i-have-to-synchronize-miktex)

Regarding the installation of `etex`, you should take a look at these other posts:

- [*.sty file not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64133/sty-file-not-found)
- [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)
- [media9.sty not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107526/media9-sty-not-found)

Basically, you should try this in your MikTeX package manger:

1. Refresh the FNBD (as administrator)
2. Synchronize Package Database

To finally ensure you have the file installed, try what was stated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64159/27833):