# Cannot install mh package with MiKTeX

Tags: errors, packages, miktex

Well, I open the MiKTeX Package Manager window, I search for the [`mh`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mh) bundle, then I try to install it, so it starts a download and says

```
Connect failed in tcp_connect()"
```

It's like it cannot connect to server. How to do this?

Comment: Follow [MiKTeX package manager, try a Synchronize Package Database](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107526/15717) and Related [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/15717), [How often do I have to synchronize MikTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107534/15717)

Comment: similar error by another user [resolved at MiKTeX issue tracker](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/discussion/33790/thread/af190f70/#5597)

Comment: @texenthusiast  im getting the same error when trying to syncrhonize

Comment: Try turning off your firewall. And, sorry if I offend, but *ensure* you're actually connected to the Internet.

Comment: @SeanAllred Yeah i fixed it, it was the damn firewall xD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your firewall isn't blocking the connection. Often, it's easiest to simply disable it completely during an update.

Comment: [Possible causes for Connectivity error at MiKTeX mailing-list](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/mailman/message/31250824/)