# How to fix "LaTeX Error: File `somepackage.sty' not found"?

Tags: packages, miktex, texworks

I am using TeXworks 0.4.5 r1280 with MikTeX 2.9 on Windows 7 64-bit. When I add

```
\usepackage{datetime}
```

and try to typeset the document, I get a dialog window like this:

[image: Package Installation Window]

I select "Install", confirm UAC request and then get the following error on the console:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `datetime.sty' not found.
```

If I try to typeset the document again - the dialog and the error appear again.

Same thing happens when I've tried installing `wrapfig` and a few other packages at random: `cases`, `comma`, `dowith`, `microtype`.  Other packages have installed fine before. What is wrong with my setup? Please let me know if you need more info about my setup in comments.

I've tried this solution: [*.sty file not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64133/sty-file-not-found). Didn't work.

Comment: Try to change the repository using the button `change`. Select another one and check you Internet connection.

Comment: Also, you can get it here http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime

Comment: Awesome. Changing the repository helped. Please add your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as such. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To other linux users, I hit this problem even though I'd just installed the .sty files with the package manager. The problem was stale temporary files and after a `make clean` (deleting dvi aux bbl files etc.) everything worked.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to change the repository using the button *Change*.

Select another one and check you Internet connection.

Also, you can get it from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime).

Note that you can decide if you want to see that dialog window every time or not.

Comment: Please add instructions on how to install it manually from CTAN.

Comment: If there is only one `sty` file you can save it at the same folder as your `tex` file. But to let it work for all users you have to save it on the right place in some `texmf` subfolder.

Comment: Man putting it in the same folder as the `.tex` file is a very welcome shortcut that works like a charm.