# file ctable.sty not found

Tags: packages

I downloaded both TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX on a new PC.

When compiling a file (which was made on another pc), I get the error `ctable.sty not found`.

Then I get the suggestion to download the correct package from the internet, but it does not work. 
How do I choose the correct "remote package repository" in the given list?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you read all those: https://www.google.com/search?q=.sty+not+found&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 ? I guess, it is a duplicate. It does not matter, which repository you take. If one is down or broken, change to another one.

Comment: "does not work" is no information, we can work with. What does not work? Downloading something from CTAN?

Comment: Dis you try with `MiKTeX Package Manager`? This package is not part of the basic installation.

Comment: Try this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152277/how-to-fix-latex-error-file-somepackage-sty-not-found

Comment: Sometimes a local "remote package repository" goes down for awhile.  Wait a while and it will (probably) start working again.  I've been getting this a lot lately.

Comment: I voted to close as unclear. as said, a package repo can be down/off once in a while. What exactlly *does not work* ... nobody knows.