# Miktex 2.9 package updating fails in miktex-update

Tags: miktex-update

Installed a [new version](https://miktex.org/download) of MikTeX to Windows7 (to different directory than earlier one. The old miktex-update didn't work, but neither does the freshly installed miktex-update. I've tried changing repositories, etc. but it fails to unknown error and log file is filled with mislocated program names, like below:

```
2017-10-22 22:46:51,005+0300 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard 2.9.6300 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit)
2017-10-22 22:48:07,164+0300 INFO  FileCopyPage - starting package maintenance...
2017-10-22 22:48:07,164+0300 INFO  FileCopyPage - installation directory: %APPDATA%\MiKTeX\2.9
--
2017-10-22 23:01:05,477+0300 INFO  FileCopyPage - initexmf: warning: The link target %APPDATA%\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/bin/x64\miktex-pdftotext.exe does not exist.
2017-10-22 23:01:05,524+0300 INFO  FileCopyPage - initexmf: warning: The link target %APPDATA%\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/bin/x64\miktex-pdfunite.exe does not exist.
2017-10-22 23:01:05,524+0300 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-10-22 23:01:05,524+0300 INFO  FileCopyPage - Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
```

Any ideas?

I tried `miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe --update-fndb` from command line and there was no errors with that.

(I've thought that there could be two different miktex installations on same machine, but it seems not, anyhow both ended up to same error. My case looks like similar like [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/mailman/message/35934035/), but there is no answer there either. Will try to reboot, maybe it helps.)

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case running the `miktex_update-admin` was the solution. The update run first with the basic modules and on the second run could pick what to update. Everything seems to be fine now.

(Afterwards rebooted and removed the other MikTex installation).