# miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason

Tags: fonts, miktex

I am very new to LaTex I am trying to work with `xcookybooky` package and get the following error message and have no idea what to do.
Sorry, but `miktex-makemf` did not succeed for the following reason:

> The fjdmw8r source file could not be found. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/Irene/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Sorry, but `miktex-makepk` did not succeed for the following reason: `PK font fjdmw8r` could not be created. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

> C:/Users/Irene/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Process exited with error(s).

Comment: Run updmap on a command line. If this doesn't help, make a complete example that demonstrates the error.

Answer (score 23):

Please run this command:

```
updmap.exe --admin
```

or

```
updmap.exe --force
```

for example:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64>updmap.exe  --force
```

Comment: Right way helped me! Any idea what's the cause? Because I updated miktex using GUI, how this command line update is different? Thank you!

Comment: It worked for me as well! How did you know that is the problem? It looks random :)

Comment: Spenser Dewey's answer explains that it's a file permission issue that's resolved by running updmap.exe.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, running `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64>updmap.exe --admin` generated a log file telling me that there was a problem with access permissions on a file, as seen in the image below.

[image: Error log of permission denied]

However, simply running `updmap` without `--admin` was enough to run the program without errors and fix my LaTeX files.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved that issue by updating all my LaTex Packages via the Miktex Console.

1. Search for the Miktex Console in Windows Start Menu
2. Open the console (in Admin mode)
3. Search for Package updates and install all
4. Run your LaTex File again.

I suppose that there was an error with my LaTex Installation since I hadn't used LaTex for about a year.