# miktex fails with a bizarre error after update on windows 10

Tags: pdftex, miktex, miktex2.9, miktex-update

I am running miktex and using texStudio. This is a file that used to compile fine. I updated my miktex and this is what I get now. Thank you in advance for any responses.

```
2022-05-21 12:03:12,774-0400 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (35992) started by miktex-makepk in directory \mik71261 with command line: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose zxxrow7z
2022-05-21 12:03:12,782-0400 FATAL miktex-makemf - The zxxrow7z source file could not be found.
2022-05-21 12:03:12,782-0400 FATAL miktex-makemf - The zxxrow7z source file could not be found.
```

Here is the ERROR from the session run as shown in TEX Studio:

```
Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.lo
g

Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log
miktex-makepk: major issue: So far, no MiKTeX administrator has checked for updates.
pdflatex: major issue: So far, no MiKTeX administrator has checked for updates.
Process exited with error(s)
```

Details of my MIKTEX Installation:

```
ReportDate: 2022-05-22 05:32:25
CurrentVersion: 22.3
SetupDate: not yet
SetupVersion: 2.9
Configuration: Regular
GitInfo: c820fab / 2022-03-13 20:15:59
OS: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit, build 19043
SharedSetup: yes
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheckAdmin: 2022-05-22 05:26:59
LastUpdateAdmin: not yet
LastUpdateDbAdmin: 2022-05-22 05:26:58
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: yes
AdminMode: yes
Root0: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: F:\Software\miktex2.9
CommonInstall: F:\Software\miktex2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

Comment: Which versions of MikTeX and TeXstudio are you using? I know some issues of Textsudio version 3 family and MikTeX after 22.(?). I'd suggest to reinstall TeXstudio, it may be the same version as you already uses. I have no idea what this `zxxrow7z ` could be.

Comment: If there is nothing against reinstall, I would reinstall.

Comment: Do you have any idea why MiKTeX tries to create this font? Can you show a small but complete example?

Comment: Ever since I watched someone trying to update MiKTeX 2.9 under Window 7 using the package manager provided with the installation of MiKTeX, and having the installation destroyed because new binaries were installed that were not compiled for Windows 7 instead of giving a message that there are no new binaries available for the operating system in use, I have refrained from using MiKTeX.

Comment: Miktex latest download from their website (basic-miktex-22.3-x64.exe. How would I find out what version of mik-tex? The console app says Conole version 4.7. Here is the download link: https://miktex.org/download/  TexStudio: TeXstudio 4.2.3 (git 4.2.3)
Using Qt Version 6.3.0, compiled with Qt 6.3.0 R

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried creating a vanilla document with just the initial preamble of the latex document. However, that compiles fine. I am not sure what aspect of my large document maybe causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following post did it. Looks like I needed to run "updmap --force". Something was amiss.

[miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411213/miktex-makemf-did-not-succeed-for-the-following-reason)