# Can't show some math symbol in beamer presentation latex

Tags: beamer, miktex

I'm trying to write a presentation which contains math equations using beamer.
But my problem is that there are some math symbols which can't show.

Here's my code example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        First Definition :
        
        Bla bla bla and $ Z_{t}(x) \neq Z_{t}(x*) $ for at least one $ t $.
        
        Second Definition :
        
        Maximize (or Minimize)
        \[Z \preccurlyeq (\succcurlyeq) Z_{0}\]
        
        subject to
        \[Ax \preccurlyeq (\succcurlyeq) b\]
        \[x \geq 0\]
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For example using this math equations code, math symbol \neq, \preccurlyeq, and \succcurlyeq make no results, just blanks.

What happened? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the output you get and your .log file? This is what I get when compiling your code  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MckZE.png

Comment: Not relevant to problem, but `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, and `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, so your preamble can be tightened up.

Comment: @barbarabeeton .... and beamer already loads the ams* packages by default :)

Comment: But I get "Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again ..." and "... So far, no MiKTeX administrator has checked for updates" when I try to run the code. Sorry I'm a beginner in using latex.

Comment: I'm not a miktex user (I very much prefer texlive), but the usual trick to solve all miktex problems is to update both in user and administrator mode. Your problem description sounds as this might be worth a try....

Comment: Maybe try this comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411213/miktex-makemf-did-not-succeed-for-the-following-reason#comment1026561_411213

Comment: This has worked for me! Thank you very much for helping solve my problem.

Comment: @Natashpa Glad to hear your problem is solved!