# Error installing packages on-the-fly

Tags: errors, packages, miktex, installing, texstudio

I set out to install all the packages `on-the-fly`. When I run texstudio (or another editor) I received a dialog box `MiKTeX Error Report` with the following error:

[image]

When I click in `OK`, the following appears:

[image]

Clicking on `Install` I receive an error message:

[image]

I am using the new MiKTeX version (`2.9.6643`) which uses MiKTeX Console for update and install packages.

This is the same problem reported in [How to fix “LaTeX Error: File `somepackage.sty' not found”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152277/how-to-fix-latex-error-file-somepackage-sty-not-found?rq=1), except that in my case the directory when the package should be installed is in blank, as shown in the last figure.

Comment: The problem is known: it is an optional file from the `arabi` package which is unnecessary. See a work-around in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313539/miktex-and-babel-missing-file-and-useless-package-installation-required).

Comment: This problem is not only happening with bblopts package but for all packages I'm trying to install

Comment: Unfortunately, no! I still don' t know the reason why this happens!