# Can I run a file using MiKTeX and TeX Live?

Tags: miktex, texlive, miktex2.9, texlive-2018

In my university the computers have MikTeX installed, but I'm having problems to install and update packages in MikTeX ([Error installing packages on-the-fly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437309/error-installing-packages-on-the-fly)).

I've never used TeX Live and due to this problem, I'd like to know if a file created in any TeX editor where MikTeX is installed would run without any problem in another computer where TeX Live is installed.

Is there a possibility of conflicting packages or something similar?

Comment: With a few exceptions (special fonts etc.) it does not really matter if you have miktex or texlive - but it can matter if you have different versions of packages. This can lead to different output. If miktex and texlive have the same version of the packages you use, it most probably gives the same output.

Comment: You can install texlive beside miktex. To switch you only need to change the PATH-variable. So you can simply try. I have both and almost all documents compile the same in both systems.

Comment: I started with MacTeX (basically TL), switched to MiKTeX, and finally to TeX Live. all created documents still compile without any issues. I do get warnings regarding deprecated packages, though. the PDF is still created without any losses.

Comment: @naphaneal MacTeX **is** TeX Live. It isn't just 'basically TeX Live'. It just comes with extra twiddly bits for the GUI.

Comment: I installed TeX Live and it's working fine on my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the packages shipped are the same, you should not experience problems trying to compile documents with TeX Live which were created using MiKTeX.

But, the same issues you can get when upgrading MiKTeX or TeX Live can also affect you when compiling with different package versions, e.g. updated packages handling things differently, deprecating old ways of doing stuff and introducing new ways.

Be aware that even my largest document (200+ A4 pages, 300+ citations, 40+ packages loaded in the preamble) only needed minimal fixing when upgrading from TeX Live 2014 to TeX Live 2018 in one go. So, from my experience, you should be totally fine doing that.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!