# Texstudio is not open and working

Tags: errors, texlive, texstudio, installing, miktex2.9

I am trying to use texStudio on windows 8, I have download texstudio-4.3.0-win-qt6.exe and install that. But when I open that then I found the error as "the procedure entry point crerated dxgiffactory2 could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Program Files\texstudio\Qt6Gui.dll". I have checked the "Qt6GUI.dll" file in "C:\Program Files\texstudio", and it is present there.
The texStudio is not able to open, I could not able to understand why it is happened.

Comment: I have also installed Miktex

Comment: As first attempt to fix it uninstall texstudio, restart the computer and install it again to see if the problem persists.

Answer (score -1):

First, I recommend you restart your computer and try again.

If that does not work, I suggest you redownload and install the `qt5` version since the `qt6` version has some bugs (see https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/2429) at least in earlier versions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have installed qt5 version and it is able to open. But, files is not able to editable, I have opened a .tex file and write some text then try to run it. The file is not changed, I found same old pdf after run the file. No error is seen there also, the file compiled without any error but no change found in pdf.

Comment: That is weird! I have never seen it before. Did you try to change your file, delete the auxiliar ones and then compile? Or did you try to run in another editor?

Comment: I have tried to change the file, as, "\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}        
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}".  I have tried to run in TexMaker editor. Same problem I have found.

Comment: I have tried to change the file, as, "\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}        
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}".  I have delete the auxiliar file but not work. I have tried to run in TexMaker editor. Same problem I have found.

Comment: I have no idea @user189810, but if you are having the same problem regardless of the editor, it is natural to imagine you are facing an installing error. 
Try to run your file on Overleaf, if it works as desired, you can confirm the above error.
If that is the case, I suggest you reinstall the `MikTeX`ditributer (if that is the one you had installed). If this procedure does not work, delete `MiKTeX`, and install the `TeXLive` distributer. I once had an installing error with `MiKTeX`, which I was not able to solve. However, after installing `TeXLive`, everything worked fine again.

Comment: You can that a look at the problem I had with `MikTeX` here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437454/can-i-run-a-file-using-miktex-and-tex-live