# getting error message using movie15 package

Tags: miktex, winedt, movie15

I am trying to embed a \GIF image in my miktex.But it is showing the message that movie15.sty not found.What causing this problem?

Comment: Check that the package `movie15` is installed on your system. The error message indicates it is not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\*.sty file not found](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64133/sty-file-not-found)