# Importing python code into texstudio

Tags: python, import

I've got some python code that I wrote and I wonder how can import the code from file.py or file.txt into texstudio instead of copying all my code again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `listing` package:

```
\usepackage{listing}

\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{path_to_file.py}
```

You'll get similar output as `minted`, except it requires no external tool and no configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the [`minted`](https://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) package that allows this kind of importing requirements. If you want to include part or all of the following file, `foo.py` in the same directory, using `\inputminted` in a listing environment.

```
def foo(a, b):
    return a + b

def bar(a, b)
    return a - b
```

This command also accepts optional parameters to specify the start line and end line, and supports an absolute path for the source file.

```
\begin{listing}[H]
  \inputminted[firstline=1,lastline=3]{python}{foo.py}
\end{listing}
```

Comment: I'm trying to run this and i get error :"File `upquote.sty' not found. \AtEndPreamble" and the file doesn't compile

Comment: I've done the pip install and it said i already had it and i still have the same problems

Comment: @ronkurman Does it work [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64133/sty-file-not-found/64150)? since I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: @ronkurman The `upquote` package is necessary for `minted` to work. What distribution are you running (TeXlive, MikTeX, different?)